# No module named 'telebot' в exe

Tags: telebot, auto-py-to-exe

autopytoexe не видит библиотеку pytelegrambotapi. Устанавливаю ее так: pip3 install pytelegrambotapi. Она ставится, но так же не находится в autopytoexe. Почему так? Может потому что она импортируется именем telebot , а ставится pytelegrambotapi? Как решить?

Answer (score 0):

Откройте раздел `Расширение` -> `Что используется и где это искать` -> `--hidden-import`

Нажмите на зеленый плюсики для добавления нового поля и напишите модуль `pytelegrambotapi`, после этого по пробуйте снова скомпилировать код

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]